# Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete on certain lines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, intellisense, visual-studio-mac

When I edit the C# Unity Scripts, they open in Visual Studio. I've noticed that the autocomplete works on some lines but it doesn't in others.

Here you can see what's going on:

[image: Moving image showing the issue]

As you can see I get the autocomplete for `GetComponent` function only when I type inside the line 19.

I also tried this:

[image: Additional picture that describes the issue]

By moving the whole `Start()` function, autocomplete seems to work, but when moving back to the original place, it seems to stop working again.

By further testing, I noticed that autocomplete does not work on lines 11 through 14 and works on any other line.

I tried updating Visual Studio, deleting and recreating the C# Script, regenerated the project files and even reimporting all assets. Nothing worked.

Unity Version: 2020.2.7f1
Visual studio: 8.9.2
OS: macOS 11.2.3

Comment: hover on the red underlined line says something?

Comment: Unfortunately the file shown in this example has been modified as I had to move on with my project. It seems the issue has disappeared and kinda "fixed itself". However, I do remember what the red underlined text said. It was the typical, "the name [name] does not exist" and it would suggest me to generate code, either a class, a field or a function.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, that's strange. Try to go into the unity editor, go to edit/preferences/external Tools and select the VisualStudio version you are using as the external script-editor.